# Get Int from String in Swift

Tags: string, int, swift

I want to make an Int from an String, but can't find how to.

This is my `func`:

```
func setAttributesFromDictionary(aDictionary: Dictionary<String, String>) {
    self.appId = aDictionary["id"].toInt()
    self.title = aDictionary["title"] as String
    self.developer = aDictionary["developer"] as String
    self.imageUrl = aDictionary["imageUrl"] as String
    self.url = aDictionary["url"] as String
    self.content = aDictionary["content"] as String
}
```

When using `toInt()` I get the error messag `Could not find member 'toInt'`. I can't use `Int(aDictionary["id"])` either.

Comment: You are so sure your `aDictionary["id"]` will always be a numeric string and number will always fit into Int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subscripting a dictionary, with the `dict[key]` method, always returns an *optional*.  For example, if your dictionary is `Dictionary<String,String>` then `subscript` will return an object with type `String?`.  Thus the error that you are seeing of "Could not find member 'toInt()'" occurs because `String?`, an optional, does not support `toInt()`.  But, `String` does.

You may also note that `toInt()` returns `Int?`, an optional.

The recommended approach to your need is something along the lines of:

```
func setAttributesFromDictionary(aDictionary: Dictionary<String, String>) {
  if let value = aDictionary["id"]?.toInt() {
    self.appId = value
  }
  // ...
}
```

The assignment will occur iff `aDictionary` has an `id` mapping and its value is convertible to an `Int`.

In action:
[image]

Comment: Ah, I understand. That you for a well written answer.